Почему не обособлен оборот с предлогом "кроме" при наличии отрицательного местоимения?
Предложение из недавней темы:
Давным-давно привыкла склонять это имя собственное. Кроме меня этого не делает никто абсолютно, смеются, говорят, что это глупость.
Почему не обособлен оборот со значением исключения, да еще при наличии отрицательного местоимения? Ведь есть же правило, которое обычно упоминается на всех учебных ресурсах:
Розенталь § 21. Обособленные дополнения.
 Как правило, при отрицательных местоимениях никто, ничего и 
 вопросительных местоимениях кто, что оборот с кроме обособляется: Никто, 
 кроме солнца и голубого неба, не глядит на него. Что, кроме осуждения, 
 может вызвать неуважение к обществу? 

Кстати, если оборот не обособляется, то он должен входить в состав предложения, например: Кроме рисунков были приложены еще чертежи (включение). А кто им тогда управляет? Или здесь, как у Булгакова, " сам и управляет"?) Какой это член предложения?
Так надо обособлять оборот или нет? Неужели грамотный человек ошибся?

Тоже иногда задумываюсь над этим вопросом. Знаю точно, что это дополнение. Но не понимаю толком, как принимать решение, насколько тесно эти слова связаны с предложением синтаксически. Обычно не обособляю, когда чувствую по интонации, что не надо - как в этом предложении.

Спасибо за голос. Да, вы правы, слышать нужно.  // Но как быть с необособленным членом?  Я уже решила,  что варианты альтернативны, как и случае обстоятельств,  и тогда нужен обычный интонационно-структурный анализ.  // Но потом вспомнила про это управление.  Пришлось придумать подходящее объяснение, чтобы не очень огорчаться) Но может кто-нибудь свое предложит...

Я как-то встречала мнение (наверное, на сайте Фоксфорда, в учебных материалах), что если объем оборота небольшой, то не стоит обособлять. Получается, от распространенности тоже зависит многое в данном случае.

Ну да, я тоже так считаю. Это и есть факультативное обособление, зависящее от разных факторов: позиция оборота, распространенность оборота и всего предложения.  Так обособляются обстоятельства, этот же принцип можно использовать для дополнений.
